# Weird black squares appear when switching tabs using wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm using wxpython to create a GUI.

The idea is that whenever I select a row, something will happen on notebook1 and notebook 2, and different tabs will appear with different related information.

However, when I bind an event when selecting a row,  weird beird black squares appear on the tab titles. What's wrong?

```
import wx
import threading
from time import sleep

class VAR():
    def __init__(self):
        self.result_row = ''
var = VAR()

class TabOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is the first tab", (20, 20))

class TabTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is the second tab", (20, 20))

class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1000, 1000), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE &
                        ~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER, pos=(100, 0))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        first_panel = wx.Panel(self.panel, size=(1000, 420))
        self.hsizer.Add(first_panel, 1)
        self.second_panel = wx.Panel(self.panel, size=(1000, 600))
        self.notebook1 = wx.Notebook(self.second_panel, size=(1000, 230))
        self.notebook2 = wx.Notebook(self.second_panel, size=(1000, 400))
        self.hsizer.Add(self.second_panel, 1)
        self.second_panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.second_panel_sizer.Add(self.notebook1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.second_panel_sizer.Add(self.notebook2, 2, wx.EXPAND)

        self.second_panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.second_panel_sizer)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.hsizer)

        var.result_row = wx.ListCtrl(
            first_panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT, size=(980, 245), pos=(0, 175))

        var.result_row.InsertColumn(0, "No.")
        var.result_row.InsertColumn(1, "2 ")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.SelectRow, var.result_row)

    def SelectRow(self, event):

        while (self.notebook1.GetPageCount()):
            self.notebook1.DeletePage(0)
        while (self.notebook2.GetPageCount()):
            self.notebook2.DeletePage(0)
        tab1 = TabOne(self.notebook1)
        self.notebook1.AddPage(tab1, "Tab 1")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.notebook1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.second_panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        tab2 = TabTwo(self.notebook2)
        self.notebook2.AddPage(tab2, "Tab 2")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.notebook2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.second_panel.SetSizer(sizer)

def InfiniteProcess():
    for i in range(100):
        sleep(0.1)
        var.result_row.Append(str(i))

finish = False
a = threading.Thread(target=InfiniteProcess)
a.setDaemon(1)
a.start()
app = wx.App()
frame = GUI(None, -1, "a")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQOQC.png)

Comment: What OS are you using to display your GUI?

Comment: @aBiologist Win 10   Does this problem only appear on Windows?

Comment: Ive tried it on Windows 7 and I didn't have the problem you have, maybe something to do with Windows 10 but not sure what exactly!

Comment: On Win 7 the problem with wxPython Phoenix it isn't as obvious (just a sort flicker in the area). You could try to place a `self.Freeze()` at the beginning of `SelectRow` and corresponding `self.Thaw()` at the end. I remember that this square is actually a window (or its remnants) with no size information but currently I can't remember how to avoid it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks a lot. But when the process of `SelectRow` is too long, `self.Freeze()` makes the whole interface freeze and less smooth.

Comment: @user6456568 An event handler (which is executed in the main thread) should never need much time to execute because the program wouldn't react to input while the handler runs. You can also try to apply the `Freeze` and `Thaw` on `var.result_row` instead of `self` to narrow down what should freeze (I don't know if this works).

Comment: By the way: It is a bad idea to do any GUI calls on another thread than the main thread. This may fail depending on call and operating system. Using `wx.CallAfter` is better.